# Undefined property: Pages::$course_model error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create dynamic pages in codeigniter. I m new to codeigniter.Following is my controller (Pages.php) code:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == false)
            {
                $this->new_course();
            }
            else
            {
                $data['course_title'] = $this->input->post('pagetitle', true);
                $data['course_intro'] = $this->input->post('courseintro', true);
                $data['created_at'] = date('Y-m-d h:i:sa');


                $data['course_slug'] = $this->seoURL($data['course_title']);
                $checkPage = $this->course_model->checkPage($data);

                // is page exists

                if($checkPage->num_rows() > 0 )
                {

                    customeFlash('You have already created this page', 'alert-warning', 'pages/create_course');

                }
```

This is my Model:

```
public function checkPage($data)
    {

        return $this->db->get_where('courses',array('course_title' => $data['$data']));

    }
```

public function add_course($data)
        {

```
        return $this->db->insert('courses', $data);

    }
```

I am getting an error:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Pages::$course_model

Filename: controllers/Pages.php

Line Number: 53

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to a member function checkPage() on null

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\vedacg\application\controllers\Pages.php

Line Number: 53

I dont have solid programming background, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Your error message is for `$this->course_model->checkPage($data);`. Where are you defining `$course_model`?

Comment: return $this->db->get_where('courses', array('course_title' => $data['$data']));

Answer (score 1):

Edit your controller 'Pages.php' using this

```
$this->load->model('course_model');
$checkPage = $this->course_model->checkPage($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

First load the course_model.php in your controller
$this->load->model('course_model');

after that you can load 
$checkPage = $this->course_model->checkPage($data);

Comment: I have i controller name:Courses.php  I had loaded  course_model in the :public function index()  -   $this->load->model('course_model'); still its not working. I had also tried to load course_model in autoload.php but didt work

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help... I was doing this worng in my model:

```
$this->db->get_where('courses', array('course_title'=>$data['$data']));
```

I corrected in this:

```
$this->db->get_where('courses', array('course_title'=>$data['course_title']));
```